# How to arrange this array according to a "parent" index?

Tags: php

There is an `array` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 131
                    [gmnu_code] => 5
                    [menu_lib] => global.menu.admin.profil
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 1
                    [menu_visible] => 1
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 1
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminProfil
                    [menu_navigation] => profil.list.titre
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 184
                    [gmnu_code] => 5
                    [menu_lib] => global.menu.admin.users
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 2
                    [menu_visible] => 1
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 1
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminUsers
                    [menu_navigation] => users.list.titre
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 130
                    [gmnu_code] => 5
                    [menu_lib] => global.menu.param.societe
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 3
                    [menu_visible] => 1
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 1
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminSociete
                    [menu_navigation] => societe.ajout.modif.titre
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 132
                    [gmnu_code] => 
                    [menu_lib] => 
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 
                    [menu_visible] => 
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 131
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminProfil/ajouter
                    [menu_navigation] => profil.titre.ajout
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 133
                    [gmnu_code] => 
                    [menu_lib] => 
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 
                    [menu_visible] => 
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 131
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminProfil/modifier
                    [menu_navigation] => profil.titre.modif
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 134
                    [gmnu_code] => 
                    [menu_lib] => 
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 
                    [menu_visible] => 
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 131
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminProfil/attribuerMenu
                    [menu_navigation] => profil.menu.attribution
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 147
                    [gmnu_code] => 
                    [menu_lib] => 
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 
                    [menu_visible] => 
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 131
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminProfil/supprimer
                    [menu_navigation] => main.suppr.profil
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 185
                    [gmnu_code] => 
                    [menu_lib] => 
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 
                    [menu_visible] => 
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 184
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminUsers/ajouter
                    [menu_navigation] => utilisateur.titre.ajout
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 186
                    [gmnu_code] => 
                    [menu_lib] => 
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 
                    [menu_visible] => 
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 184
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminUsers/modifier
                    [menu_navigation] => utilisateur.titre.modif
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 187
                    [gmnu_code] => 
                    [menu_lib] => 
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 
                    [menu_visible] => 
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 184
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminUsers/reinitMdp
                    [menu_navigation] => utilisateur.titre.reinit.mdp
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [menu_id] => 188
                    [gmnu_code] => 
                    [menu_lib] => 
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_ordre] => 
                    [menu_visible] => 
                    [menu_deleted] => 
                    [menu_parent] => 184
                    [menu_controlleur] => AdminUsers/supprimer
                    [menu_navigation] => utilisateur.titre.suppr
                )

        )
      ...
}
```

In this `array` there is the notion of parent in the data : the key "menu_parent" means that an `array` is the child of another `array` ; the `array` having its "menu_id" equal the value of "menu_parent" is the parent.

For example in the above example the `array` having "menu_id" 131 is the parent of the arrays having "menu_id" 132 , 133 , 134 and 147.

I want to rearrange the sort of the `array` so that all childs of an `array` of a particular "menu_id" are all just placed after it. How to do that ?

Comment: Did you tried anything. Post your attempts what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid ambiguity, lets say that, if the whole array has the following schema:

```
array [
  subarray_0,
  subarray_1,
  ...
];
```

then your need is to sort the content of each `subarray_N` *independently* from other ones.

If so, you can work like this:

```
foreach ($array as &$subarray) {
  usort($subarray, function($a, $b) {
    switch (true) {
      case $a['menu_parent'] > $b['menu_parent']: return 1;
      case $a['menu_parent'] < $b['menu_parent']: return -1;
      default: return 0;
  }
}
```